# Collect month, day, year individually using html 5 input type "date"

Tags: css, html

How would I collect the month, day, and year individually? I currently have this for my drop down form box:

```
<input type="date" value="DOB" name="dob" class="required">
```

Is there a way to do this or will i have to create 3 separate ones? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Date, Month, and Year from Javascript "Date" form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597361/parse-date-month-and-year-from-javascript-date-form) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825363/how-do-you-parse-a-date-from-an-html5-date-input

Comment: Are you wanting to collect the values with php, javascript?

Comment: No i just want to send them via URL.