# Javascript - get a date from an HTML input

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

I am currently trying to take the value from an HTML input (below)

```
<input type="date" id="dateInput" />
```

and put it into a javascript variable so I can use it for other things. I currently am using the code below.

```
    var input = document.getElementById("dateInput").value;
    var dateEntered = new Date(input);
```

But when I test those variables, it tells me that *Input* is "" and *dateEntered* is "Invalid Date".

I've tried the .valueAsDate instead of just .value as well. When I test those out, it tells me that *Input* is null and *dateEntered* is "Wed Dec 31 1969 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" even though I entered today's date.

How would I fix this so that the javascript variables actually reflect the date I enter? I am using Google Chrome as my browser.

**EDIT and UPDATE**
For those who wanted my whole code, indentation is a little off sorry:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Calculate Time</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />  
   <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
      <h1> Calculate Time </h1>
   </header>
   <article align="center">
      <div id="cities">
          // My navigation links here (REMOVED)
      </div>
  <div id="caption">
     Calculate the time elapsed since a date entered.
  </div>
   <div class="box">
       <article>
           <form>
               <fieldset>
                   <label for="dateEntered">
                       Enter a Date
                   </label>
                   <input type="date" id="dateInput" />
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset class="button">
                   <button type="button" id="determineTime">Find Time</button>
               </fieldset>
               <fieldset>
                   <p>Time Elapsed is:</p>
                   <p id="time"></p>
               </fieldset>
           </form>
       </article>
   </div>
   <div id="map"></div>
  </article>
    <script>
        var input;
        var dateEntered;

        document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function () {
        input = this.value;
        dateEntered = new Date(input);
        });

    /* find and display time elapse */
    function lookUpTime() {
        // More code will go here later.
    }

    // add event listener to Find time button and clear form
    function createEventListener() {
        var submitButton = document.getElementById("determineTime");
        if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", lookUpTime, false);
        } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
            submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", lookUpTime);
        }
        document.getElementById("dateInput").value = "";
        // clear last starting value on reload
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "";
        // clear previous results on reload
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", createEventListener, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListener);
    }
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the entire JS code?

Comment: At which point do you set those variables? If you set them at page load, then obviously the value will be empty. Show a complete example please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse a date from an HTML5 date input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825363/how-do-you-parse-a-date-from-an-html5-date-input)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var input = this.value;
    var dateEntered = new Date(input);
    console.log(input); //e.g. 2015-11-13
    console.log(dateEntered); //e.g. Fri Nov 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
});
```

Basically you need to listen for the change of your date input, currently you were trying to get the value on load, when the picker has no date in it hence you get 'Invalid Date'

Comment: well your answer is correct till user enter Date in ISO format: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS but the OP haven't specifed the format

Comment: I assumed the date will be modified from the input type 'date', and from my understanding there is no way to provide it in other formats other than yyyy-mm-dd ??

Comment: @CY5 `<input type="date">` is always in that format.

Comment: @Juhana well input type date is what Chrome support which has good datepicker all that stuff.. but in firefox and IE 10 its not check this out https://jsfiddle.net/73ebffud/1/

Comment: Oh thank you! The first console.log(input) works great. But my problem now is that the 2nd console.log(dateEntered) is showing one day earlier than it is supposed to. When I enter 11/11/2015 it says Tue Nov 10 2015....

Comment: @Arnatuile   input type date  is a concept Google came up with and is in their whatwg specifications (not official) and is only partially supported by Chrome by Chris Love http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983013/how-to-get-html-5-input-type-date-working-in-firefox-and-or-ie-10#answer-22983753  so your date format will not work in FireFox and IE 10 whatever user enters it will take that format   check here example  https://jsfiddle.net/73ebffud/2/    you get that bug becoz you might be doing it in IE10 or firefox

Comment: Like i stated in my post above, I am using Google Chrome, not IE or firefox.

Comment: @Arnatuile Which version of Chrome are you using? That's a very strange behaviour which I can't seem to reproduce in Chrome 46

Comment: I have Version 46.0.2490.80 of Chrome.

Comment: @Arnatuile your format of Date is wrong 11/11/2015 chrome accept the date YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Well when you add an input box with type="date" it auto shows IN THE BOX  mm/dd/yyyy. I did not format anything. You can then select a date from a calendar or type it. Then it goes into the variable input as "2015-11-11" just fine. The problem is when you go from the variable "input" and try to make it a date variable "dateEntered". It subtracts a day for some reason. Is there a way to just add one day to it? So in a way it corrects it.

Comment: @Arnatuile I copied part of your code from above and added 2 console logs: https://jsfiddle.net/fduho9sb/  on my machine the output seems consistent between the 2 variables, could you have a look at this ?

Comment: @luanped For me those two are different. I tried it in Edge too. So maybe it is just my computer?  it still says the second console.log is a day short.

Comment: @Arnatuile its not your browser Date() take time from your internal system not from any server or anything else

Comment: Maybe I will just take my input variable and take out the different parts of it. The whole goal of this assignment (its for a class) is to take a date in from a user and calculate how much time has passed in years, months, and days. I am supposed to use .getFullYear() .getMonth() and that jazz. But this is not going well for me.

Comment: You could have a look at http://momentjs.com/ - might be of help for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: FYI: These events will fire with a blank value if the keyboard is used to select a date that is not valid. ie. Feb 30.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48564568/html5-input-type-date-input-event-incorrectly-fires-with-empty-value/48564701#48564701