# Get date from input and print ony date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get date from input and print only date on but something is wrong with my code Please help me to rectify it.

Here is the code:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("dateInput").value; 
var d = new Date(input);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getDate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript get Date</h2>
<input type="date" id="dateInput" />

<p>The Date is:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript - get a date from an HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659508/javascript-get-a-date-from-an-html-input).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - get a date from an HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659508/javascript-get-a-date-from-an-html-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add an event listener to listen event of input change:

```js
document.getElementById("dateInput").onchange = function(){
    var input = this.value; 
    var d = new Date(input);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.getDate();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript get Date</h2>
<input type="date" id="dateInput" />

<p>The Date is:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

See [onchange Event - W3C School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [jqueryui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as this date field won't support across all browsers

```js
document.getElementById("dateInput").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var input = this.value;
    var dateEntered = new Date(input);
    console.log(input); 
    console.log(dateEntered); // GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dateInput">
```