# jQuery: How to get the date format mmddyyyy format from the HTML5 datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm using HTML5 date input tag, as per the date picker it is taking `mm/dd/yyyy` format but while retriving the date from the date input field I'm getting `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Is there any way to get the "`mm/dd/yyyy`" ? Please suggest me. Here is the sample code,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#idButton").on('click', function(){
  var fromDate = $("#fromEffectiveDate").val();
  console.log(fromDate);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="date" id="fromEffectiveDate" />


<input type="button" id="idButton" value="GetDate" />
```

Comment: you can use [`valueasdate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825411/5980430)

Answer (score 1):

For best browser compatibility, I'd suggest to use [jQuery date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) plugin instead of HTML5 date input.

It supports `dateFormat` option

```
$( "#fromEffectiveDate" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
});
```

The suggestion is based on the facts that

- you have `jQuery` already
- and HTML5 date input is [unsupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#browser_compatibility) in Safari and IE
- even [MDN suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#handling_browser_support) to use jQuery date picker plugin

> At the moment, the best way to deal with dates in forms in a cross-browser way is to have the user enter the day, month, and year in separate controls, or to use a JavaScript library such as [jQuery date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split("-").reverse().join("/")` to split date and then reverse that array and finally join it to get `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idButton").on('click', function() {
    var fromDate = $("#fromEffectiveDate").val().split("-").reverse().join("/");
    console.log(fromDate);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="fromEffectiveDate" />


<input type="button" id="idButton" value="GetDate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

vanilla js solution with `valueAsDate`

```js
function test(){
  let date = document.getElementById('fromEffectiveDate').valueAsDate;
  console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()+1}-${date.getDate()}`);
}
```

```html
<input  type="date" id="fromEffectiveDate" >
<input type="button" id="idButton" value="GetDate" onclick="test()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property:

> [valueAsDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement): Date object: Returns / Sets the value of the
> element, interpreted as a date, or null if conversion is not possible.

After getting the date value you can convert it in the format desired using [.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString):

```js
$("#idButton").on('click', function(){
    var fromDate = $("#fromEffectiveDate")[0].valueAsDate;
    
    var options = {  year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
    var dateFormatted = fromDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
    
    console.log(dateFormatted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input  type="date" id="fromEffectiveDate" />


<input type="button" id="idButton" value="GetDate" />
```